# In macOS Photos app, can you export all pictures of a person?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I'd like to export all the pictures that Photos.app has tagged as a particular person. Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose People view from library <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and drag the person to the destination folder in Finder.

Works in macOS Mojave (I don't know if it works in previous versions as well).